# Barcode scanner triggers next button onclick event and popup window JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a simple form with a button at the end of each row to open a popup window on onclick event.

The problem I have is I fill the form textfields with a barcode scanner which always triggers the form and onclick event in the buttons.

I have have managed to stop the form from submitting with some small script but now the problem is the barcode scanner triggers the onclick event inside the button so the popup window opens every time I use the scanner..

Here is the code I have so far :

Jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

function stopform(){
    // Retrieve the code

```
var code =document.getElementById ('code').value;
// Return false to prevent the form to submit
return false;
```

}

HTML table :

```
<tr>
<td>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" id="code" name="code" class="form-control"  onchange="oncode_change(this.value)"   />
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="qte" id="qte" class="form-control" value="1" onkeyup="onqte_change(this.value)" />
</div>
</td>
<td colspan="4"><div id="txtHint3" style="width: 100%"> </div></td>
<td><button onclick="Popup=window.open('rabais.php?type=article&option=argent&pos=1','Popup','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=500,height=400,left=430,top=150'); return false;"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Rabais $</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button onclick="Popup=window.open('rabais.php?type=article&option=pourcentage&pos=1','Popup','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=500,height=400,left=430,top=150'); return false;"  class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Rabais %</button></td>
</tr>
```

If somebody can point me to a solution to stop the onclick call it will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your barcode scanner adds **Carriage Return** char (hex 0x0D, decimal 13) at the end of actually scanned barcode value.

Carriage Return is invisible char also produced by pressing **Enter** key on keyboard (key code == 13) and it usually triggers button's on_click event.

If my assumption is correct, you'll be able to solve your problem by disabling Enter key on your web page. This [link](http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-disable-enter-key-on-forms) might give you hint how to do it using JQuery.

Comment: Hi, thnk you for your answer. I did try to stop the the enter with code `<script>
$("form").keypress(function(e) {
  //Enter key
  if (e.which == 13) {
    return false;
  }
});
</script>  ` but I don't know why it doesn't work. I still hit enter and it still opens the popup. Any why idea wouldn't be effective?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve it using type="button" inside the button element which cause most browser to stop the onclick event from being called when hitting enter.

Thanks!